# WPF drag & drop from windows explorer ZIP preview

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am handling files drag & drop from the windows explorer to my WPF application (.NET 4.8) so far so good with simple files and by using `DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)`. But now I want to handle drop from files dragged from a zip file opened as a preview in the windows explorer (so **not unziped**).

I didn't find anything with WPF, Forms or simply in C# at all. For Outlook attachements I am using [OutlookDataObject](https://gist.github.com/MattyBoy4444/521547) by seening of this work I guess that for my case I should know exactly what is the format used by the windows explorer with zip files, didn't find much about that though. I am ok with unziping the file myself and getting the specific file I need in but I don't know where to get the path of parent zip file and relative path of the file being D&D.

So if someone already have a solution for that, or documentation about the format used by the explorer during this kind of drag & drop, or ways to inspect the DataObject to get those myself I will be really glad.

Comment: Have you debugged this to see inspect what is getting passed to you?

Comment: @JimFoye to use `IDataObject.GetData` you have to know the format (was about to try to get everything with `GetData(typeof(string), false)`). Though I have just seen that you can have a list of avaible format with `IDataObject.GetFormats()`

Comment: Also would love to know why someone just decided that this question was not good enough and should be closed for "A community-specific reason" - -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name of the dropped file(s) in the zip archive using the FileGroupDescriptorW stream. The `OutlookDataObject` does this for you:

```
OutlookDataObject dataObject = new OutlookDataObject(e.Data);
string[] fileNames = dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW") as string[];
```

There is no way to get the path to the parent zip file using this data. What you should do is to grab the contents of the dropped compressed file(s):

```
MemoryStream[] fileContents = dataObject.GetData("FileContents") as MemoryStream[];
if (fileContents.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (MemoryStream fileStream in fileContents)
    {
        // convert to string:
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that's way easier that what I thought it would be, will try and accept if it work :)